# how can i show index column with the genres only in my dataset

Tags: python, pandas, word2vec

Here is a screenshot of what my dataframe looks like:
[image]

I want to display something like this as my output with the index that you see in the screenshot:

Output -
pop: `[1,3,10,11]` #wherever pop is present in index position
rock : `[11,20,16,26,30,100 ......]` #wherever rock is present in index position

Which means the "pop" is present only in `[1,3,10,11]` these index columns &
I would like to display it for all the Genres present in my dataset.

Comment: Whenever you post questions like this always try to attach data also.

Comment: I recommend you to read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
It is hard to help you if it's hard to reproduce your original data frame. Also we need to know what exactly is the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
pop = list(songs_df[songs_df['Genre'].str.contains('pop')]['Index'])
rock = list(songs_df[songs_df['Genre'].str.contains('rock')]['Index'])
```

Comment: @Abishek Kumar, I tried this it didn't work for me, and there are many genres around 500 including sub-genres.

Comment: then you must have list of them somewhere, so that  you can iterate over them.

Comment: how about `pop = list(songs_df[songs_df['Genre'].astype(str).str.contains('pop')]['Index'])`